# Create finite element solver particle ensemble to fill a specifically shaped hollow volume

Tags: modeling

A colleague mentioned that blender (or Houdini, but I'd like to try blender first) would be an apt tool for creating an ensemble of particles, with particular shapes, that would fill the inside of a specifically prescribed volume. The shapes would, for the first problem I'm looking at, just be spherical. The individual spheres might be comprised of hexahedral elements. The system of particles would, ultimately, be exported to exodus file format.

Does anyone in the community have any relevant suggestions, feedback, etc.? Thanks for any help you might be able to offer!

Comment: I think this question would be better asked at somewhere like [Blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org) rather than here. This Q&A site is specifically here to answer questions about problems using Blender and its built-in addons. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.